# MySQL with counters

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, window-functions

My query:

```
SELECT name FROM users
```

It's possible add a counter for each differente name. For example:

```
mark  1
john  1
mark  2
louis 1
john  2
Ann   1
```

Thank you

Comment: what value has `counter` and how is it to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn FROM users
```

This assumes that you have another column, called `id`, which can be used to sort the records (that would typically be the primary key of your table).

If you don't have such column, you *can* remove the `ORDER BY` clause of the window function - but the results of the query are then unstable, meaning that is not guaranteed that a given row will consistently get the same row number over consecutive executions of the same query. Depending on your use case, this might, or might not be what you want.

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can emulate `row_number()` with a correlated subquery:

```
select name, 
    1 + (select count(*) from users u1 where u1.name = u.name and u1.id < u.id) rn
from users u
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!